# How to libpq copy into two tables concurrently in PostgreSQL?

Tags: python, postgresql, concurrency, libpq, psycopg3

I am listening to `n` different TCP streams and would like to `copy` the received data into `n` different tables after some simple post-processing. Latency is important, and using this approach sequentially I've managed to get insertions down to < 1 ms.

Using `libpq` from Python, I've attempted to open `n` different database connections with

```
db = ps_abst.PGconn(
    ps_impl.PQconnectdb(f"user={settings.db.user}".encode(pg_encoding)))
```

from `n` different `threading.Thread` targets and simply `put_copy_data(data)` the post-processed data after executing the relevant `copy` query with `db.exec_(query)`. `ps_abst` and `ps_impl` are imports from [psycopg](https://pypi.org/project/psycopg/).

It seems, however, that this approach is incorrect as the `copy` operation either fails silently or I receive a warning that an ongoing `copy` operation is in progress. The TCP data can, on the other hand, be printed to `stdout` without issues.

Does anybody know where I'm messing up? Thanks a lot!

Comment: It does work to import multiple table with COPY concurrently through different database connections. Make sure that your code doesn't mix connections between threads, otherwise it would indeed produce random failures.

Comment: I've managed to solve the problem; I had messed up one of the constraints, making the ```copy``` operation fail silently sporadically, depending on whether that particular constraint was broken... Thank you very much for your help!